# How To Run Shaving Machine Without Bettary?

Tags: resistors, voltage-regulator, diodes, dc-motor, charger

I'm just an amateur in this and I Need Help..

I've drawn this circuit of my Shaving machine
and I want to remove the battery and connect it directly to one of these phone chargers-:

The first: output 5.7v ~ 800mA

or

The second-: output 5v ~ 350mA

or

-The shaving machine charger: 3v ~ 200mA

Will Any Of These Work?
[image: Shaving machine]

Comment: If the motor is intended for 1.2 volt operation, neither the 5 volt or 5.7 volt power supply is suitable.  If the existing battery is dead, you should replace it with a NiMH cell, rather than trying to run the thing from random external power supplies.

Comment: @PeterBennett I have tried to run the Motor directly with the charger 5v
the Motor was fast and very powerful but the problem when the blade was placed on the Motor did not move at all 
So I think it should be to connect Resistor Or something else

Comment: https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-DC-Buck-Step-down-Converter-1-25V-1-5V-1-8V-2-5V-3-3V-5V-3A-Voltage-Regulator/322586242419

Comment: @BruceAbbott Thanks but I think we can modulation this circuit by adding some thing or replace

Comment: A DC/DC converter is the only 'thing' you can add that could make your supply work. Otherwise get a replacement battery.

Comment: @BruceAbbott what if i replaced the motor with anther motor 3v ??

Comment: buy a mini360 buck converter for 50c on aliexpress and use that to produce the 1.2V your motor wants.

Comment: @VoltageSpike What is the function of the Diode in my circuit?

Comment: @FreeBird What circuit, all I see is a PCB, you need to reverse engineer the circuit